# populate a hypotenuse table in c

Tags: c

I’m new to programming, and some concepts are still hard for me to understand, so I'm here to ask for your help.  The following code calculates the hypotenuse of a right triangle by populating an array table with random values for side A and B.

The one thing I would like to modify in this code is instead of having it fill the table with random values; I would want to be able to enter my particular values. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>   //header for input/ output
#include <math.h>    //header for sqrt() and pow() 

double calcHypotenuse(double a, double b)
{
    double a_square = pow(a, 2);
    double b_square = pow(b, 2);
    return sqrt(a_square + b_square);
}

//Print the table of a,b,c with headings  

void printTable(double table[4][3])
{
    int i;

    // display the header columns
    printf("%19s%21s%21s\n", "Value for Side A", "Value for Side B", 
"Hypotenuse");

// display the data rows
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("%15.3f%21.3f%23.3f\n", table[i][0], table[i][1], table[i][2]);
    }

}

int main()
{
double array[4][3];   //two dimensional array to store values of a, b and Hypotenuse 
double a, b, c;      //variables  of side A, B, and C 
int i;             // loop index variable

//populate the table with rand values for a and b 
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    a = 2 + rand() % 16;
    b = 3 + rand() % 10;
    array[i][0] = a;
    array[i][1] = b;
    array[i][2] = 0;
}

// print the array table 
printf("\nInput Table:\n");
printTable(array);

//populate the hypotenuse values in the array table 
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    a = array[i][0];
    b = array[i][1];
    c = calcHypotenuse(a, b);
    array[i][2] = c;
}

// print the results 
printf("\nOutput Table:\n");
printTable(array);

return 0;
}
```

Again, the expected result is just for me to be able to input values for side A and B and have the calculations displayed in the output table.

Comment: This can be either from stdin or from a text file, you have to be more specific.

Comment: Greg K. I want to be able to interact with the code. Currently, if you execute the code it will display the results based on the rand values. I don't want to use rand values.

Comment: So what you want is that you want to interactively set the angles for a number of triangles  by yourself?

Comment: FYI, the [C languate provides the `hypot()` function.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.7.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such simple cases, it is really easy to use `scanf` in order to fetch input from the terminal and store it on code variables. I modified a bit your code to provide functionality for arbitrary input as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>   //header for input/ output
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>    //header for sqrt() and pow() 

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 100

double calcHypotenuse(double a, double b)
{
    double a_square = pow(a, 2);
    double b_square = pow(b, 2);
    return sqrt(a_square + b_square);
}

//Print the table of a,b,c with headings  

void printTable(double table[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3],  int n)
{
    int i;

    // display the header columns
    printf("%19s%21s%21s\n", "Value for Side A", "Value for Side B", 
"Hypotenuse");

    // display the data rows
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%15.3f%21.3f%23.3f\n", table[i][0], table[i][1], table[i][2]);

}

int main()
{

double array[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3];   //two dimensional array to store values of a, b and Hypotenuse 
double a, b, c;      //variables  of side A, B, and C 
int i;             // loop index variable

int n;
printf("Input Number of Triangles ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Parsing Input Table\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf ("%lf", &a);
    scanf ("%lf", &b);

    array[i][0] = a;
    array[i][1] = b;
    array[i][2] = calcHypotenuse(a, b);;
}

// print the results 
printf("\nOutput Table:\n");
printTable(array, n);

return 0;
}
```

When you run the code, you will be prompted to input first the number of triangles and then each of the side lengths one by one.

However in practice it is really convenient to generate an input file and using scanf you can send the input file to the program right away without having to input your values one by one all the time.

For example in my case I generated this input file `input.txt`:

```
6
1 2
3 4
5 6
3 4
7 8
10 11
```

on linux (and probably on mingw as well) you can pass it to the program as follows

```
a.out < input.txt
```

and it generates the following output:

```
Output Table:
   Value for Side A     Value for Side B           Hypotenuse
          1.000                2.000                  2.236
          3.000                4.000                  5.000
          5.000                6.000                  7.810
          3.000                4.000                  5.000
          7.000                8.000                 10.630
         10.000               11.000                 14.866
```

Just a general note: Be very careful with scanf because it can cause undefined behavior. Try to validate the input values before continuing with your computations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanf()` to read input, and you can store that input into a variable. 
For example:

```
double num;
scanf("%lf", &num);
```

In your case, you can remove the part where you assign random numbers to `a` and `b`, and store user input into `a` and `b`.

scanf() has different options and conversion specifications, check https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to change is to be able to input the values yourself you can replace the code inside the loop that generates random numbers with :

```
//populate the table with rand values for a and b 
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the value of a : ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("Enter the value of b : ");
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    array[i][0] = a;
    array[i][1] = b;
    array[i][2] = 0;
}
```

then you'll be prompted 4 times to enter the values of a and b.